# Why does backslash '\' work so differently in linux?

Tags: linux, sed

When I put single quotes around backslash like  this

> echo '\'

it prints the backslash, it does not care for escaping.

but when I use the same thing in sed like this

> sed 's/\/a/g' : trying to replace backslash with a

or in case of grep

> echo '\\//' |grep '\', it does not work and it requires escaping as well.

why does this backslash need to be escaped? I mean inside all of these lose their meaning right?

Comment: Re your `sed` command: You mean forward-slash and in order for the replacement to work, you need to ensure you have three delimiters: `sed 's/\//a/g' file`. Note that you can use [other characters as delimiters](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2), for example: `sed 's%/%a%g' file`. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with backslash is that it has many special meanings, for multiple tools and multiple contexts.

Within single quotes, it loses special meaning for your *shell* (please learn to tag your questions with its name when it's relevant or when you're unsure), but it retains special meaning for `sed` (it is special for *regular expression* syntax, so it's expected for `sed` and `grep`)

Usually you can *escape* a backslash instead of *quoting* it. It doesn't necessarily make things readable, but in some contexts, it can. That's how I grep a literal `\` without quotes:

```
grep \\\\
```

Shell turns `\\\\` into `\\`, and `\\` in regular expression means literal `\`.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that grep '\\' and grep \\\\  are the same, it is super confusing :(